# How to select rows which are repeated (opposite to distinct)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have column named application_id in my table , it contains values like

```
32,
65,
75,
75,
32,
45,
56,
78,
64
```

I just want to get the values which are repeated

like 75,32

I think its somewhat opposite to distinct. I don't know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
SELECT a_id FROM mytable GROUP BY a_id HAVING count(a_id) > 1
```

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to select `application_id` then simply use the query already suggested by [@Sayonji](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18952151/1369235)

```
SELECT application_id FROM MyTable GROUP BY application_id HAVING count(*) > 1
```

But if you want to select all columns then you can achieve this using a sub-query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM MyTable
WHERE application_id IN
(
   SELECT application_id FROM MyTable
   GROUP BY application_id
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

Or using a self-join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.* FROM MyTable t1
JOIN
(
   SELECT application_id FROM MyTable
   GROUP BY application_id
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t2
ON t1.application_id = t2.application_id;
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e77c6/4)